# Feynman amplitude calculation for a Feynman diagram of gravitons in xAct

Tags: xact, example

Any tutorial example how to calculate Feynman rules from a Lagrangian of gravitons in xAct and how to implement it for calculating its Feynman amplitude for a given diagram involving gravitons in xAct? Any pedagogic tutorial available?

Comment: As far as I know, xAct doesn't compute Feynman diagrams, period. It is used to handle tensor algebra for general relativity. If you want Feynman rules, Feyncalc is the package you want to be using. You may be able to copy the Lagrangian over from xAct and use it within Feyncalc.